# Why Ubuntu's Orca don't read Java Frames?

Tags: ubuntu, java, orca

Why Ubuntu's Orca don't read Java Frames on my desktop application?

Is it for everyone, or just for me?

All other applications are normally read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Orca to work with Java applications, you need to install the "Java Access Bridge". For Ubuntu, install package libaccess-bridge-java.

For details see http://live.gnome.org/Java%20Access%20Bridge